# Rails testing assert_select vs assert_selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, documentation

As I understand it, `assert_select` is a Capybara method for testing the state of an HTML `<select>` element, and `assert_selector` is for testing the presence of any HTML element and its inner text.

Why then, does:

```
assert_select "h1", "Foobar"
```

Work, when `h1` is not a `<select>` element? The [Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) seems inconsistent here.

Comment: I guess it is just checking the current contents of the h1 tag? Will it fail when you change the value to something different?

Comment: Are You using https://github.com/rails/rails-dom-testing gem? Which type of test You are in?

Answer (score 3):

**To the original question**

`assert_select` and `assert_selector` have no relation to the html tag `<select>`. That's it.

**To those who comes here for the difference between `assert_select` and `assert_selector`**

- `assert_select`

  - is an assertion provided by [`rails-dom-testing`](https://github.com/rails/rails-dom-testing) gem based on `nokogiri` gem.
  - is used to assert DOM elements in the `responce`.
  - thus, aims for integration tests.
- `assert_selector`

  - is an assertion [provided](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/system_test_case.rb#L114) by `Capybara` gem.
  - is used to assert given selector is on the page or a descendant of the current node. Furthermore, it will wait for the selector to appear on the page, if not exists and not time out.
  - thus, aims for system tests.

Comment: Hmmm. There is another assert_select, that defined by Capybara in Capybara::Minitest::Assertions#assert_select, which delegates to has_select? I think this is the source of the confusion.

Comment: Agree. Since Capybara::Minitest::Assertions#assert_select [calls #assert_selector internally](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/3.37.1/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb#L39), the differences here apply as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some misunderstanding with terms.

CSS-selectors are patterns used to select the element(s) you want to style. And `assert_select` is used for selectors testing (not only for `<select>` elements).

There is the link in your question to Rails Guide. From [there](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-views):

> The `assert_select` method allows you to query HTML elements of the response by using a simple yet powerful syntax.
>
> There are two forms of `assert_select`:
>
> `assert_select(selector, [equality], [message])` ensures that the equality condition is met on the selected elements through the selector. The selector may be a CSS selector expression (String) or an expression with substitution values.
>
> `assert_select(element, selector, [equality], [message])` ensures that the equality condition is met on all the selected elements through the selector starting from the element (instance of `Nokogiri::XML::Node or Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`) and its descendants.
>
> For example, you could verify the contents on the title element in your response with:
>
> ```
> assert_select 'title', "Welcome to Rails Testing Guide"
> ```
>
> You can also use nested `assert_select` blocks for deeper investigation.
>
> In the following example, the inner `assert_select` for `li.menu_item` runs within the collection of elements selected by the outer block:
>
> ```
> assert_select 'ul.navigation' do
>   assert_select 'li.menu_item'
> end
> ```

Comment: Actually if I use it (Rails 6 system test) `   assert_select "a.dropdown-toggle", "Finance"` I got `expected to find visible select box "a.dropdown-toggle" that is not disabled but there were no matches`.  This is because it goes to Capybara `assert_select` not ActionDispatch `assert_select`(moved after Rails 4 to gem https://github.com/rails/rails-dom-testing)

Comment: But Capybara::Minitest::Assertions has an assert_select that specifically delegates to `Node::Matchers#has_select?`, which is for grabbing `select` elements. I think @Foton has indicated the source of the confusion: are there _two_ definitions of assert_select? One in Capybara and one in Rails?

Answer (score -1):

you probably want:

```rb
assert_selector "h1", text: "Foobar"
```

Comment: Correct. But the question is "why does assert_select work, when h1 is not a select element?"

Comment: this does not address the question at all, hence downvote